# How can I make this jquery work how I want to?

Tags: jquery

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/cgweb87/r3NEX/

When you click on the h2, it slides the div up and down but how can I make it so that it slides the div up and the other sections below it slide up to sit under the h2, rather than the div sliding up to sit on the h2 below.

Hard to explain but please check the fiddle,

Comment: do you mean you want the h2 to stay in the same place while the div slides up underneath it?

Comment: Yes, you explained it a lot better.

Comment: haha thanks, I'll have a look

Comment: Sounds like you want the vertically aligned content to act more like columns?

Comment: so you want the rows below it to all move up to? or stay where they are?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think all you need to do to get what you want is add: style="vertical-align:top;"  to your townSection class

```
.townSection {width: 30%; display: inline-block; vertical-align:top;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r3NEX/13/

Comment: thanks for the fiddle Abe! I edited his to test the theory but then forgot to save it and link it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick change to your CSS:

```
.townSection {
    width: 30%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

With this, the h2 stays in place, the content under it rolls up.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/r3NEX/12/

this work for you?